# how can I convert react javascript to type script?

Tags: typescript, formik, ant-design-pro

```
import React from "react";
import { DatePicker, Form, Input, TimePicker, Select } from "antd";

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const { Option } = Select;

const CreateAntField = AntComponent => ({
  field,
  form,
  label,
  selectOptions,
  submitCount,
  type,
  ...props
}) => {
  const touched = form.touched[field.name];
  const submitted = submitCount > 0;
  const hasError = form.errors[field.name];
  const submittedError = hasError && submitted;
  const touchedError = hasError && touched;
  const onInputChange = ({ target: { value } }) =>
    form.setFieldValue(field.name, value);
  const onChange = value => form.setFieldValue(field.name, value);
  const onBlur = () => form.setFieldTouched(field.name, true);
  return (
    <Form className="field-container">
      <FormItem
        label={label}
        help={submittedError || touchedError ? hasError : false}
        validateStatus={submittedError || touchedError ? "error" : "success"}
      >
        <AntComponent
          {...field}
          {...props}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onChange={type ? onInputChange : onChange}
        >
          {selectOptions &&
            selectOptions.map(name => <Option key={name}>{name}</Option>)}
        </AntComponent>
      </FormItem>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

I am new in typescript I need to convert this file to typescript, which is an ant design component.
I have got these Errors :

'field' implicitly has an 'any' type.
 'form' implicitly has an 'any' type.
'label' implicitly has an 'any' type.
'select options' implicitly has an 'any' type.
 'submitCount' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Parameter 'name' implicitly has an 'any' type.
 Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.
 Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.
 Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: Try set `noImplicitlyAny` flag into false in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: But I am going to convert it

Comment: That's great, by let's migrate app step by step. You need a lot of time to turn on `noImplicitlyAny` flag because you have to manually type most of this errors.